# Proper way to get URL params on React component mount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have a component for which I want to get URL params (say, a1 and a2). If these contain anything, I want to set some local state to their values so things can be rendered on the page. I'm using `react-router-dom` and the `withRouter` HOC, so I can access `location` from `props`, but I'm not sure if I can use that. Right now I have:

```
class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      a1: null,
      a2: null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(window.location.search);
    const parsed = querystring(window.location.search);
    this.setState({
      a1: parsed.a1,
      a2: parsed.a2,
    })
  }
}
```

Now, doing this gives me an ESLint warning for `Do not use SetState in ComponentDidMount`. I've done some searching and that's apparently 'ok' to do in a callback from `componentDidMount`, but this isn't a callback, so I'm not sure if it's 'ok'.

So what's the right thing to do here? Do I ignore the warning (and get the double-render)? Is there some other way to properly get URL params and set them to local state?

I also don't want to use any methods that will be deprecated in React 17, since that just means re-writing it on upgrade...

Comment: Any reason you can't use `componentWillMount`?

Comment: `componentWillMount` is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version of React

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason why you are storing these values in the state?

You said it was "so things can be rendered on the page"

However, you don't need to use the state for that. In `render()`, you can access and use `this.props`.

Comment: If you don't store in state then you don't have to worry about keeping it in sync with the url.

Comment: What Keith said. I mean, technically yes I could use the URL as 'state' for the information, but that seems wrong. If someone goes to my site from an existing shared link with params, I want that to initialize my values (which can subsequently change with UI interactions).

Answer (score -1):

You should use `componentWillMount` method instead. It'll be preparatory setup and once state is set, your component can render normally, unlike re-render in case of `componentDidMount`.

In case you don't want to use `componentWillMount` because of deprecation in future (`UNSAFE_` is still valid even after React 17 though), you can also set url params in `constructor` itself, as this are constant value and do not change at all.

Comment: I don't want to use components that will be deprecated in React 17.

Comment: Even if componentWillMount weren't going away, it doesn't actually prevent a component from re-rendering if you set state from there.

Comment: `componentWillMount` cannot rerender as at this point component is not yet rendered once.

Comment: If you're not doing anything big, just like this example, componentWillMount is going to be completed before render for sure.